# Make tooltip for migrated posts on localized sites human readable

Tags: bug, localization, tooltips, migrated-questions, unicode

Tooltip for migrated post on localized sites, e.g. on [Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501940/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-txt-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)*  contains URL encoding and completely unreadable:

> [image: migrated hint]

Could it please be fixed to display not only Latin symbols?

Same for link tooltip in [comment](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6340/%D0%90-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment24590_6340):

> [image: URL encoded tooltip]

---

<sub>* (according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339794/339911) banner with migrated status removed after 60 days since migration)</sub>

Comment: Are you sure this is still an issue? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340844/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel the main issue is encoded text in tooltip irrespective the place of the source of that tooltip. If there is no more issue in migrated posts I think we can change/rename the current question.