# Auto-generated link to duplicate truncated in the comment

Tags: bug, comments, duplicate-questions, localization, automatic-comments

[Auto-generated link](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6340/%D0%90-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment24590_6340) for possible duplicate on ruSO.meta produces truncated text in comment section:

> [image: truncated]

This happened possible due to a long URL-encoded title of the original question.

Possible solution is to use the post URL like in the share link, but without a user id.

Comment: Also, please [don't forget](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301176/339911) about an [ugly tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcTQV.png).

Comment: Yeah the internet isn't made for cyrillic letters....